# Adding and Multiplication of Pure Tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Consider the tensor product $V\bigotimes W$, and $v_1\otimes w_1$, $v_2\otimes w_2$ in $V\bigotimes W$, where $V$ and $W$ are $F$-algebras.

Can we add or multiply the pure tensors as follows?

$(v_1\otimes w_1)(v_2\otimes w_2)=v_1v_2\otimes w_1w_2$

$(v_1\otimes w_1)+(v_2\otimes w_2)=(v_1+v_2)\otimes (w_1+w_2)$

Something tells me that the above is not quite right?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The multiplication is often defined that way for associative algebras by extending linearly, and it works, but the addition is not correct. In general not every element of $V\otimes W$ can be written as $v\otimes w$ for $v\in V$ and $w\in W$. Instead we have the rules
$$(v_1+v_2)\otimes w=v_1\otimes w+v_2\otimes w$$
and similarly for $v\otimes (w_1+w_2)$. It may very well be in a given case that $v_1\otimes w_1+v_2\otimes w_2$ can get no simpler than that, and of course more than two terms may be required in general.